# USB flash drive mounts and unmounts automatically

Tags: linux-mint, usb

Whenever I plug my flash drive into the usb, a message like this window appears on the screen:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/sajjad/Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 64-bit: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/sajjad/Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 64-bit"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

What can I do about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:
I repartitioned my flash drive using gparted. Then right clicked on the flash drive's icon and opened it as root and changed the owners permission to read and write.

Answer (score 1):

Your usb drive partition is damaged.
Probably, a power fault or removing before datas was written.

Run a Check disk (chkdsk) from windows if you have one.

In linux, ntfsfix or fsck.ntfs.

Comment: This is the resualt:
`Failed to determine whether sdb1 is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access 'sdb1': No such file or directory
Error opening 'sdb1': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access 'sdb1': No such file or directory
Error opening 'sdb1': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access 'sdb1': No such file or directory
Error opening 'sdb1': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
`

Comment: Ok.

"$MFTMirr does not match $MFT" is telling you that the Master File Table is damaged.

Has you tried to run chkdsk from windows?
Has you tried run fsck.ntfs on linux?

what message you are getting?

Answer (score -1):

It's not a matter whether you can or cannot mount, if in the first place Linux refuses to acknowledge there are USB 3.0 devices attached and turned on before booting.

Linux Mint 16 fails to even notice there are two HDD connected to a USB 3.0 docking station. Similar error never happens under Windows environments.

I think it a lack of proper USB 3.0 drivers for archaic Linux platform.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Once you have [sufficient reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), you can leave a comment below a post to critique or request clarification from an author.